# Yii2- common function for some controllers- where write code

Tags: yii2

I have such tables: book and person. One book can be at one person's hands. I created form for book in gii. In the form I can write the name of a book and select a person, which took the book. In book's controller i write

```
 return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'persons_dropdown' => getDropdown('app\models\Person', 'name'),
    ]);
```

"persons_dropdown" is the array like 1=>"John Smith", 2=>"Stan Green".
The function getDropdown is:

```
public function getDropdown($model, $colomn)
    {
        $rows = $model::find()->orderBy('id')->asArray()->all();
        return ArrayHelper::map($rows, 'id', $colomn);
    }
```

The question is- where i should replace function getDropdown() (this function is universal function for any controller and it would be used in some controllers)? Or may be i can get the necessary array by yii tools, without my function.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651613/how-to-write-global-functions-in-yii2-and-access-them-in-any-view-not-the-custo/36555983#36555983

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is create an helper for this type of function

Essentially you could create a proper class in your model and then refer to the related function/method by declaring (public static)

```
use common/models/YourHelper;


YourHelper::yourMethod();
```

Someone create a personal  vendor and add this kind of common function in an helper subdir